# Markov Chain Question using probability generating function

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, generating-functions, markov-process

We have a markov chain with states $\{1,2,3,4,5 \}$ with $A = \{1,5\}$ being our absorbing states. We take a step forward with probability P, and step backwards with probability Q.

Let $T_k $ be the number of steps to hit $A$ (either 1 or 5), and let $k = 1,2,3,4,5$

Using $ G_k(s) = E(s^{T_k}) $ as the probability generating function, we want to show that $$ G_3(s) = \frac{(p^2+q^2)s^2}{1-2pqs^2} $$

So, I'm kind of lost on how to start this. What is the first step to tackling a question like this?

Comment: perhaps a pun was intended -- the answer is to apply "first step analysis".  I.e. calculate  $\mathbb E(s^{T_k}) = \mathbb E\big[ \mathbb E(s^{T_k}\vert X_1)\big]$.  that puts you in state 2 or 4.  And apply first step analysis there to be absorbed with probabilities p,q respectively or recover the original PGF (i.e. value at state 3).  Conceptually you are looking for a generating function for the hitting time of absorbption, which was this thread  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521200/generating-function-for-the-hitting-time-of-a-markov-chain/3521464

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'm  not too sure I understand you though. How does conditioning the expected value bring us to state 2 or 4,

Comment: what if I asked about a simpler question of $\mathbb E(T_k) = \mathbb E\big[ \mathbb E(T_k\vert X_1)\big]$ -- could you relate $\mathbb E(T_k\vert X_1)$ to the expected times until absorbtion from states 2 and 4?

Comment: If our absorbing states are 2 or 4, wouldnt the expected time just be qs + ps? I dont know if I answered your question or not.